# How to get Current logged in User in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have setup a parametrized job to deploy on several environments. Now i want to restrict deployments to some environments based on the LDAP-groups of the current user.

I am  using Dynamic Choice Scriptler for the above task but issue i am facing is that **User.current()** is returning value **SYSTEM**. Is there any way to find out the current user without triggering the build?

Comment: Had you considered the Build User Vars Plugin?https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin

Comment: Build User Vars  will give you the user that started the build, not the current logged in user.